# Trying to move the decimal place in an output

Tags: sql

this is a simeple on i did some research but could not come up with the answer to this

as of now i have a data like this

0.1428571428571428571428571428571428571429

want the output to be like

1.4

I have tried so far
but unable to come up with the desired result thanks in advance

select  to_char(round(0.1428571428571428571428571428571428571429 *100,2),'999.9'    ) from dual;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with:

```
SELECT ROUND(0.1428571428571428571428571428571428571429 * 10, 1)
```